# What is the best way how to submit form and add props?

Tags: reactjs

please, what is the best way in React how to achieve:

- submit form (and..)
- redirect to another page (and..)
- have some props from the origin form here?

I have discovered two possibilities how to redirect:

Source article: https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-programmatically-navigate/

1) with React Router: `history.push()`

2) with React Router: `<Redirect />`

---

1) With `history.push()`: Redirecting works but i have no idea how to add custom props to redirected page.

2) With `<Redirect />`: adding custom props works (in this way):

```
<Redirect to={{ pathname: '/products', state: { id: '123' } }} />
```

But redirecting does not work to me, I keep receiving errors after submission.

Source code:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { withRouter, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'

class App extends React.Component {

    state = {
        toDashboard: false,
    }
    handleSubmit = () => {
        this.setState(() => ({
            toDashboard: true
        }));
    }
    render() {
        if (this.state.toDashboard === true) {
            return <Redirect to={{
                pathname: '/products', state: { id: '123' }
            }} />
        }

        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Register</h1>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default withRouter(App);
```

Errors:

- Warning: You tried to redirect to the same route you're currently on: `/products`"
- Form submission canceled because the form is not connected

[image]

What is the best way how to achieve my target, please?

Answer (score 1):

You need to cancel the default submit action.

so change you `handleSubmit` method to

```
handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
        toDashboard: true
    });
}
```

Comment: This is definitelly good point, but i am still receiving: 
Warning: You tried to redirect to the same route you're currently on: "/products"
And Render method in Products is not executed so i have empty DOM.

Comment: @RadekAdler can you post how you have set up your routes ?

Comment: I guess i have resolved it thank to you. I will post the whole code for people who are looking for working submission pattern. I did not know that for simple redirection i have to set Routes too (shame). Thank you Gabriele.

Answer (score 0):

What is finally working fine to me is code below here.
From App.js it is routed to Products.js, then i click on the button and it is redirected to NotFound.js and i can reach props "state: { id: 123 }" and i display it here.
Hope it will help to someone who is looking for some working submission patern.

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import Products from './Products';
import NotFound from './NotFound';
import Home from "./Home";

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path="/products" component={Products} />
                    <Route path="/notfound" component={NotFound} />
                    <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
                </Switch>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default App;
```

Products.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Products extends Component {    
    handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.history.push({ pathname: '/notfound', state: { id: 123 } });
    }

    render() {
        console.log(this.props);    
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Products</h1>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default Products;
```

NotFound.js

```
import React from "react";

const NotFound = (props) => {
    console.log(props);
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Not Found</h1>
            <h2>{props.location.state.id}</h2>
        </div>
    );
};    
export default NotFound;
```